# Auto DHCP IP Phones to a different subnet

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dhcp, voip

I'm standing up a 3CX PBX system in my office and would like to set my DHCP to assign IP phones a 10.10.8.x address, while giving everything else a 10.10.0.x address (our current net).

What would be the proper way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

1. Set up a VLAN
2. Put your phones onto that VLAN
3. Put a DHCP Forwarder on the VLAN (your switch should be able to do this). Point the forwarder to the IP address of your existing DHCP server
4. Put a scope on your DHCP server that covers the subnet that the DHCP Helper is assigned to

If you are using the piggy-backing function on your phones to plug your PC into your phone, you will need to enable VLAN trunking on your phone ports on your switch and enable both the data and voice VLAN, and configure your phone to use a different VLAN for its computer port.

Comment: My confusion is in step 2. How do I put my phones on the VLAN? Is that a phone/pbx setting?

Comment: @JoeJMCIT It's a setting in your switchgear.

Comment: @JoeJMCIT You can configure the native VLAN on your switchport as the phone VLAN and just plug it in, and if you're using the piggyback port then enable that port for trunking of the data VLAN. Or if your network is more complex, you might need to pre-configure your phones for 802.1q tagging on the phone configuration as well.